# Maven WildFly Plugin: Could not execute goal deploy

Tags: java, maven, plugins, wildfly

I want to deploy my war-files with the maven wildfly-plugin.
I use the `wildfly-8.2.0.Final`-version and I was to force to change the port of the management-console to http://127.0.0.1:9990.

This is my maven configuration:

```
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
                <configuration>
                    <jbossHome>C:\wildfly-8.2.0.Final</jbossHome>
                    <hostname>127.0.0.1</hostname>
                    <port>8080</port>
                    <serverConfig>standalone-full.xml</serverConfig>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I get following error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.705 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-02-01T22:46:43+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/171M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.0.2.Final:deploy (default-cli) on project wildfly: Could not execute goal deploy on C:\Users\laudatio\Documents\Java\wildfly\target\wildfly.war. Reason: I/O Error could not execute operation '{
[ERROR] "operation" => "read-attribute",
[ERROR] "address" => [],
[ERROR] "name" => "launch-type"
[ERROR] }': java.io.IOException: Unknown service name
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: sorry my fault! I meant that I changed the port number of the management-console to 127.0.0.1:9999 !

Comment: Shouldn't you have `<port>9999</port>` then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message isn't great, it's been [fixed upstream](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFMP-18), but the issue is you've got the wrong port defined. The plugin uses the management port which by default is `9990`. If you change the configuration to `<port>9990</port>` or leave it off it should work.

A side note most of the configuration you have is not needed. The `jbossHome` and `serverConfig` are only needed for the `run` and `start` goals. If you're just deploying you don't need any of that configuration defined. The defaults should be correct.

Comment: i do not understand it: I have to move the port from 9990 to 9999 because some nvidia services are listening to port 9990; but it does still not function - again the same error; could it be something different? perhaps I forgot to change something in the standalone-full.xml?

Comment: If you changed the management port to `9999` then you need to use `<port>9999</port>` in the plugin configuration.

Comment: Sorry but i have changed to port 9999 and still build failure with the error above.....

Comment: Is the server listening on `127.0.0.1`? Can you connect to http://127.0.0.1:9999?

Comment: I'm not sure what it could be then. If you can access the web console then it should work. Try running with -X to get a stack trace.

Comment: i solved the problem by moving to port 8888 - thank you for the answers anyway

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the problem could be one of the following:

- The deployment of any archive (jar, war, ear) through wildfly-maven-plugin plugin will happen only if the WildFly is listening at its management port which is 9990 by default. So make sure that WildFly is listening at its management port.
- If WildFly is listening at its management port then check if your host file located at ***%SYSTEM_ROOT%\System32\drivers\etc*** for windows machine is configured correctly. i.e. your local host is mapped correctly for both IPv4 and IPv6.

  127.0.0.1 localhost
  ::1    localhost